# ActiveDataProvider - вывод записей, начиная с указанного ID

Tags: php, yii2

Каким образом можно выбрать данные из БД путем ввода цифры, после которой будут выбираться данные.

```
$provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Stations::find()->where('is_visible = 1'),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => Yii::$app->request->get('sfrom'),
                'page' => 0
            ],
            'sort' => [
                'defaultOrder' => [
                    'order' => SORT_ASC
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = 123; //Id начиная с которого будут выводится записи(не включительно)
'query' => Stations::find()->where(['>', 'ID_STATION', $id]);
```